# Fatal Error in magento 1.8 after enabling google analytics

Tags: php, magento

I just hit save config button after enabling google analytics in magento and all of a sudden entire website is showing following error

Fatal error: Class name must be a valid object or a string in /home/indianf1/public_html/includes/src/__default.php on line 29663

I am not able to access admin panel as well.

before this the site was woring alright.

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: It is an unusual path. What is the path to index.php of your Magento root?

Comment: Try this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13377491/magento-fatal-error-class-name-must-be-a-valid-object-or-a-string

Comment: Yes @Malachy its an unusual path because its the path to an automatically generated file after the compilation process. I have solved the issue, and, needless to say, it was a good learning experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after much research and reading much of Magento developer documentation I am finally able to resolve this issue. Here I am answering this question in hope to help anyone else who is facing the same problem or similar problem.

This issue is related to Magento's compile feature. In one quick line, the solution is to manually disable the compilation feature. Since I was unable to log into the admin panel. This had to be done manually.

Rename the includes folder to includes.old (or anything else). It will disable the compilation feature and store will load without compilation.

And the compilation can be again enabled without any hassle, by using the usual way by navigating to **system_tools_compile**.